# Minhog of Boruch Schneerson

Tags: minhag, chabad, nuschaot, chassidic-rebbe

Rabbi Schneur Zalman Schneerson founded Lubavitch Chassidus but what nusach did his father Boruch follow?

Comment: This is a comment: (why can't I leave comments??)
you can even ask the same question about Rabbi Schneur Zalman himself. he only put his nusach together later on in life. what nusach did he pray till his own nusach was finalized?

Comment: Rabbi Schneur Zalman Boruchovitch, his son the Mittler Rebbe's last name was Schneuri, and the Tzemach Tzedek was called Schneerson. The father, Boruch, was a student of the Bal Shem Tov, but his family was from Bohemia originally. If he was davening with early Chassidim, then he was probably using some sort of Chassidic nusach like Sefard. His family most likely used Ashkenaz before.

Comment: @DavidKenner, if he was from Böhm, he likely followed a variant of the old Minhog Österreich, as was followed in Prague. (Minhog Österreich eventually split and developed into Minhogei Polin/Lita)

Comment: More like Boruch Schneerfather. (Schneur Zalman Schneerself?)

Comment: @DoubleAA :) Is this Jews, or Judaism?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I doubt it. Boruch was a chosid. He most likely davened some variant of Nusach Sfard. As for before he became a chosid and _his_ father's nusach, you're probably correct.

Comment: @ezra, Graetz asserts in *Gesch.* vol. 5 that most early chassidim orened Nusach Ashkenaz, at least until the Besh"t's death, or rather, he asserts that most switched to Nusach Sfard under the Mezriczer Maggid. FWIW at least one Nusach Ashkenaz siddur exists in R' Yisruel b' Eli'ezer's own hand and resides in Chabad's library in Crown Heights.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt The Besht having a Nusach Ashkenaz siddur does not really say much. Siddurim were not mass-produced as they are today, and back then, Nusach Sfard siddurim were not really printed... In the days of the early Chassidim, a Nusach Ashkenaz might have been used but changes might have been made here and there ba'al peh to make it more in accordance with the Arizal. The printing of the Nusach Sfard siddur was a later invention.

Comment: @ezra, siddurim were actually printed in fairly large quantities by the early 18th century, whether they were available in Podolia is a separate question, although I would infer that they were, if sufficient amounts of paper or klaf were available for handwritten siddurim. There are apparently two siddurim in the Besh"t's own hand, one in Ashkenaz and one in Sfard (which is not the same Sfard as Chabad uses)